# When emacsclient open with eval using use-package it opens waiting M-x

Tags: emacsclient, use-package, eval

I am trying to create a bash alias to open emacs with a calendar from terminal. To do so I am using calfw with use-package like so:

```
(use-package calfw
  :ensure ;TODO:
  :config
  (require 'calfw)
  (require 'calfw-org)
  (setq cfw:org-overwrite-default-keybinding t)
  (require 'calfw-ical)
  :bind ("C-c q" . 'cfw:open-org-calendar))
```

When I try to do

```
em --eval "(execute-extended-command (cfw:open-org-calendar))"
```

it opens with the calendar open, but it waits for a M-x command

[image]

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the help for `execute-extended-command` (via `C-h f execute-extended-command`):

> It is bound to , , M-x.
>
> (execute-extended-command PREFIXARG &optional COMMAND-NAME TYPED)
>
> This function is for interactive use only;
> in Lisp code use ‘command-execute’ instead.
>
> Read a command name, then read the arguments and call the command.
> To pass a prefix argument to the command you are
> invoking, give a prefix argument to ‘execute-extended-command’.

This tells us that `execute-extended-command` is for *interactively* prompting the user for the name of a command to run. It is the command that is run when you enter `M-x`, so it makes sense that your client opens with the `M-x` prompt waiting for you.

If you want to execute a function in elisp, you just need to call that function, you don't need to wrap it in `execute-extended-command`:

```
em --eval "(cfw:open-org-calendar)"
```